# nesting partials in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, partials

I have created two partials: _listDialog.rhtml and _list.rhtml.

the listDialog partial has all the code that the list partial contains + additional code for the dialogbox.  this results in duplication of code.

how do I solve this?  if I include the list partial in the listDialog partial, then we'll have nested partials (a partial inside a partial)

any ideas?

Comment: Are you against nesting the partials?  Or are you asking how to nest partials?